# Understanding module design patterns in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to understand module patterns in Javascript so that i can separate my code into different modules  and use them where required.

```
var messageHandler = (function(){
    var el;
    var display = function(a){
        if(a=='error'){
            el = $('.error');
            el.css('display','block');
        }
        else if (a==='success'){
            el = $('.success');
            el.css('display','block');
        }
        else if (a=='warning'){
            el = $('.warning');
            el.css('display','block');
        }
        else if (a=='danger'){
            el = $('.danger');
            el.css('display','block');
        }
        registerClick(el.find('.close'));
        return this;
    }
    function registerClick(p_el){
        p_el.bind('click',function(){
            hide();
        });
    }
    var hide = function(){
        el.css('display','none');
    }
    return {
        display: display,
        hide: hide
    }
})();
window.messageHandler = messageHandler;

messageHandler.display('warning');
```

So, I  have four different classes in css for different types of messages.The close class is for a small cross button on the top right to close the message.
This works fine till i call the function only once.When i do this

```
messageHandler.display('warning');
 messageHandler.display('success');
```

Now both the messages close button have been bind to the success close button because el gets overwritten.

How to achieve it keeping the code reusable and concise.

Comment: For starters, how about refactoring to `el = $('.' + a);` and simply do an `el.show()` at the end to show it?

Comment: Just let your `hide` function take a parameter (the element), and don't make your `el` module-wide available. Just like you have done with `p_el` for `registerClick`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that you have a closure variable `el` that you are overwriting every time `display()` is called. The `hide()` function uses whatever is the current value of `el` at the time it is called, so overwriting `el` is a problem.

If you want to have "static" functionality like this `display()` method, you need to avoid shared state.

As @Bergi points out in the comments, you can eliminate the shared `el` and modify `hide()` to take an element as input:

```
var messageHandler = (function(){
    var el;     // delete this
    var display = function(a){
        var el; // add this
```

```
function registerClick(el){
    el.bind('click', function(){
        hide(p_el);
    });
}
function hide(el){
    el.css('display','none');
}
```

You could also modify `hide` to make use of the current event properties, and then just have:

```
function registerClick(el){
    el.bind('click', hide);
}

function hide(event){
    $(event.target).css('display','none');
}
```

Cleaned up version including the auto-hide discussed in the comments:

```
var messageHandler = (function(){
    var display = function(a){
        var el = $('.' + a);
        el.css('display', 'block');

        var hideAction = function () { el.css('display', 'block'); };
        var token = setTimeout(hideAction, 5000);

        el.find('.close').bind('click', function () {
            hideAction();
            clearTimeout(token);
        });

        return this;
    }

    return {
        display: display
    }
})();
```

Comment: thanx it works....but i have also made hide method public, so that  can use set timeout to hide the message after sometime.I cant pass the el now.

Comment: @namankalkhuria Great. I hadn't noticed that you were making the `hide` method public, but the `function hide(event)` syntax should still be fine if you are doing that.

Comment: @namankalkhuria Ok, good point. I missed that. But in that case, how is `hide()` supposed to know which element you want to hide? Is it just supposed to hide all the open message boxes?

Comment: thats why i had used el as global...  so that hide knows which element to hide (works only for one box),,but since we are talking about multiple message box in the page ... i dont know how to achieve it...I ideally i  would like both the messages go away after say 5 seconds,good point about hideall .. i can add a hideall public and call it when i have more than one boxes... thnx for the input

Comment: @namankalkhuria In that case, how about having the module auto-hide it after 5 seconds? Please see my edit.